# Prolog: 'cut' in query vs. rules/facts

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

Doing exercise 10.4 on [learnprolognow](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse46), could someone explain to me or help me visualize why for `?- p(X),p(Y)` we get:
`X=1,Y=1; X=1,Y=2; X=2, Y=1; X=2, Y=1.`
And not just
`X=1, Y=1; X=1, Y=2.`

I think I'm misunderstanding how the cut happens, when it's in the ruleset instead of the query - because I think I can visualize it for `?- p(X),!,p(Y).`, where it actually behaves as I thought the last one would...

Edit: From the website

```
% database
p(1).
p(2):-!.
p(3).

% Queries
p(X). % returns: X=1; X=2.
p(X),p(Y). % returns: X=1,Y=1; X=1, Y=1; X=2, Y=2. (?)
p(X),!,p(Y). % returns X=1, Y=1; X=1, Y=2.
```

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Cuts_and_Negation

Comment: Thanks, I already had a look at it, but I'm missing why for `p(X),p(Y)` it backtracks to change X's value ?

Comment: `p(X), p(Y)` backtracks to `p(X)` because that's simply how Prolog works. The cut in between, `p(X), !, p(Y)` prevents backtracking to `p(X)`. In other words, once `p(X), p(Y)` succeeds, Prolog will backtrack and try to find another `Y` that also makes it succeed. Once those options are exhausted, it backtracks further to find another `X` to enable `p(X)` to succeed and then moves forward to `p(Y)` again (starting fresh from the `p/1` facts).

Comment: So the cut in the rules, doesn't prevent backtracking of the query?

Comment: Yes, it  does. Do you see `X = 3` or `Y = 3` in any of your solutions? You  don't because of the `p(2) :- !.`. Prolog never gets to checking `p(3).`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this problem you can imagine a tree with `X` in as first level and `Y` as second level (prolog uses sld resolution that can be well described with a tree). Consider this problem:

```
p(1).
p(2):-!.
p(3).

sol(X,Y):-
    p(X),
    p(Y).
```

I've added the predicate `solve/2` to make it more clear. Run the query:

```
?- solve(X,Y).
```

First of all you have to choose the value for `X`. Prolog uses depth first search from the top to the bottom, from left to right. So it evaluates `p(x)`: `p(1)` succeed (because is the first clause, if you write `p(2)` above `p(1)`, `p(2)` will succeed) and so `X = 1`. Then evaluates `p(Y)`: `p(1)` succeed and so you have the first solution:

```
X = Y, Y = 1.
```

If you click on more, then prolog does a backtrack (you can imagine this as a step above on the tree) and tries another value for `p(Y)`. In this case `p(2)` succeed, the predicate is true and you get:

```
X = 1, Y = 2.
```

Now, if you click on more, due to the fact there is a cut (`!`) in the body of `p(2)` (a general rule in prolog has the form `head :- body`), prolog will not go more in depth and `p(3)` is ignored. So there's no more solution to `p(Y)`. So there is another backtracking and this time, for `p(X)`, `p(2)` succeed and `X = 2` and for `p(Y)`, `p(1)` succeed and you get:

```
X = 2, Y = 1.
```

If you click on more, you get:

```
X = Y, Y = 2.
```

Now, due to the fact there is a cut after `p(2)`, there are no more solutions available for both `X` and `Y` (`!` cuts everything below `p(2)`).

If you remove the cut you get all the possible solutions:

```
X = Y, Y = 1
X = 1,
Y = 2
X = 1,
Y = 3
X = 2,
Y = 1
X = Y, Y = 2
X = 2,
Y = 3
X = 3,
Y = 1
X = 3,
Y = 2
X = Y, Y = 3
```

Keep in mind that the order of the clauses is important. If you write

```
p(2).
p(1):-!.
p(3).
```

You get

```
X = Y, Y = 2
X = 2,
Y = 1
X = 1,
Y = 2
X = Y, Y = 1
```

You can check this behaviour using the tracer. In SWI or SWISH you can write `?-
 trace, solve(X,Y).`

If you have a situation like this:

```
p(1).
p(2).
p(3).

sol(X,Y):-
    p(X),
    !,
    p(Y).
```

prolog will tests all the possible values for `Y` and only one value for `X` because the cut stops the exploration of the tree (ideally you have 3 branches for `X` (1,2,3) and 3 for `Y` (1,2,3), `!` cuts 2 and 3 from `X`) and you get:

```
X = Y, Y = 1
X = 1,
Y = 2
X = 1,
Y = 3
```

Sorry for the long post, hope to be clear.

Comment: Thank you, but why does this: _So there is another backtracking and this time, for p(X),(...)_ happen? Shouldn't the cut stop all backtracking? Or does it only stop backtracking until _a certain level_ ?

Comment: The cut, yes, stops the backtracking. In this case you test `p(1)` then `p(2)` for both `X` and `Y`. In this case `!` stops the backtracking only for the predicate `p/1`, not all the backtracking.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you very much :)